# apache 2.2 with php 5.3 and miscrosoft sql 2008 crash

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, sql-server, sql-server-2008, php5

I am using Apache 2.2 with PHP 5.3 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 64-bit. Every 3 to 5 hours, I get the error in the event viewer that Apache crashed for 20 seconds and then resumed.

The error is:

> Faulting application httpd.exe, version 2.2.14.0, time stamp
>   0x4ac181d6, faulting module ntdll.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, time
>   stamp 0x49e03824, exception code 0xc0000005, fault

Answer (score 0):

if I'm not mistaken but I don't believe there is an official 64 bit release of Apache for windows. My first guess would be that 32 bit apache isn't playing nicely with the 64 bit operating system.

There are some unofficial 64 bit compilations of apache that might be worth trying, but don't know if that would solve your issue or not. This would just be my first step.